# Access text field from another View Controller and passing data

Tags: swift

[image]
[image]

So I have two ViewControllers, FamilyController and FormFamilyController,
I want to access FamilyBudget text field form FamilyController in FormFamilyController.

Comment: Please post your code as code, not images. Please also read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the level of detail in your question.

Answer (score 0):

use this for push to next ViewController.you also push any textfield data to another ViewController.

```swift
let destinationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerNameID") as! ViewControllerName
destinationViewController.a = FamilyBudgettextfield.text
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationvc, animated: true)
```

take a variable to second view controller like

```
var a = String()
```

maybe its help for you.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of navigation,

**step 1 :-  write this code in FamilyController class**

```
let obj = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FamilyController") as? FamilyController
 obj.textField = BudgetField.text! 
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj!, animated: true)
```

**step 2 : - In FormFamilyController controller , define a new variable like that :-**

```
 var textField = String()
```

**step 3 :- check and print value in  FormFamilyController ,**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    Print("Your Text Field is \ (textField)") 
    }
```